# independence of inner product in relativity

Tags: special-relativity, metric-tensor

> "Notice that the definition of a tensor does not mention components of the vectors. A tensor must be a rule which gives the same real number independently of the reference frame in which vectors' components are calculated"

Is a sentence picked from Schutz's General Relativity book chapter 3.2 on definition of tensors.

Now I arbitrary choose 2 vectors;

$A(1,0,0,1)$ and $B(5,0,3,4)$ first component being the time component. And I define metric tensor $g$, $g(A,B)=\vec{A}\cdot \vec{B}=4-5=-1$

I also know that $\vec{B} \cdot\vec{B}=0$ is invariant. And I can write $B$ as $B=(1,0,0,1)$ in a suitable reference frame.

Now if I use components of $B$ in this second frame $g(A,B)=1-1=0$

But this way inner product depends on the reference frame of individual vectors. Where am I making a mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking at two different vectors, $A$ and $B$, which you specify in some frame where $A = (1,0,0,1)$ and $B = (5,0,3,4)$. You compute that $B \cdot B = 0$, fine. Then you remark that $B_\text{new} = (1,0,0,1)$ in some suitable frame --- also fine. However, this means that you're performing a Lorentz transformation, defined by some $4 \times 4$ matrix $L$. In this new frame, the coordinates of $A$ also change to $A_\text{new} = L \cdot A_\text{old}$. If you compute $g(A_\text{new}, B_\text{new})$, you should get back the original answer.

Comment: oh ok So I need to perform this operation in same set of frames. For a second I thought the sentence I picked from Schutz meant that both vectors can be chosen from different set of reference frames.

Comment: To prove the equivalence you use the rule that $L^\mathrm{T} \eta L = \eta$ where $\eta$ the Minkowski metric. The two matrices $L$ and $L^\mathrm{T}$ come from the fact that you're Lorentz transforming both vectors, not just one of them.